# Message templates preview: "Can only have one anonymous define call per script file"

Tags: wordpress, angular

Not much about this apart from "message templates preview doesn't work" statement.
Throws multiply Developer Console error messages.

```
Uncaught Error: Can only have one anonymous define call per script file
    Angular 2        enqueueDefineAnonymousModule
    jQuery 2
angular-modules.d4dbe599d7906c7ca9d7d39f15881dd0.js:formatted:5423:62
```

and also these 500 errors:

```
POST
/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/ajax/api4
[HTTP/2 500  607ms]
Request: '{"examples":["ExampleData","get",{"language":null,"where":[["tags","CONTAINS","preview"],["name","LIKE","workflow/contribution_online_receipt/%"]],"select":["name","title","data"]}],"adhoc":["WorkflowMessage","getTemplateFields",{"workflow":"contribution_online_receipt","format":"example"}]}'
```

Would've been happy to help & provide more information, just don't know which and how.

- Wordpress 6.4.2
- CiviCRM  5.68.0.